# Copy file to documents directory (sandbox) from main bundle

Tags: ios, filepath, appstore-sandbox, mainbundle, documentsdirectory

I need to copy some png to documents folder from the main bundle at the first run of my app. I need it because  I have to save the file path of these images in a core data entity.

I tried in that way, but it don't works, anybody knows why?

```
// to copy image from main bundle to documents folder

NSString* mainBundleFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"SbriciolataDiRicotta" ofType:@"png"];

NSArray *destPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [destPath objectAtIndex:0];

 NSData *mainBundleFile = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:mainBundleFilePath];
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:documentsDirectory
                                        contents:mainBundleFile
                                      attributes:nil];

// to save the file path

NSString*nomeImmagine = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"SbriciolataDiRicotta"];
NSString *pngFilePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@.png",documentsDirectory, nomeImmagine];
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`createFileAtPath` expects as argument the path of *file* to be created, not the path 
of the enclosing *directory*.

Remarks:

- You can also use `copyItemAtPath:toPath:error:` to copy the file without loading
  the entire contents into memory.
- The usage of `initWithFormat` to assign a constant string is unnecessary.
- `stringByAppendingPathComponent:` is the correct method to append a path component.

Comment: I tried this: [[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtPath:mainBundleFilePath toPath:documentsDirectory error:nil]; but don't works.

Comment: @Totka: As I said: The argument is the *file path*, not the directory.

Comment: How can I get the file path? isn't [destPath objectAtIndex:0]?

Comment: @Totka: No, that is the Documents directory. `NSString *destPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"image.png"]` would be the target path.

Comment: No, but i solved  my problem in another way. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @Totka Could you share your answer here, explaining how you solved it? Thanks.

Comment: @Neeku I've posted the answer

Answer (score 0):

How to save

```
-(void)saveImageWithID:(NSString*)ID{
    //[self saveImageWithID:<#(NSString *)#>];
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    NSString* imageName = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@",ID];
    NSString *pngFilePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@.png",documentsDirectory, imageName];

    UIImage *image = self.fieldImage.image;
    NSData *data1 = [NSData dataWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)];
    [data1 writeToFile:pngFilePath atomically:NO];
}
```

How to load from sandbox

```
-(void) loadImageFromPathInsideView
{
    // [self loadImageFromPathInsideView];
    Contatto* contact =[[DataManager sharedClass]dammiIlTuttoIlContattoDellaCella:self.indice];
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES);

    NSString* imageName = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@", contact.nome2];
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString* path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@.png",documentsDirectory, imageName];;
    UIImage* image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path];
    self.fieldImage.image = image;
}
```